# How can you get the shared instance from AnyClass using a protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift, casting, static, protocols

In the past we've used Objective-C to anonymously get the sharedInstance of a class this way:

```
+ (nullable NSObject *)sharedInstanceForClass:(nonnull Class)aClass
{
    // sharedPropertyProvider
    NSObject<KVASharedPropertyProvider> *sharedPropertyProvider = [aClass conformsToProtocol:@protocol(KVASharedPropertyProvider)]
        ? (NSObject<KVASharedPropertyProvider> *)aClass
        : nil;
    if (sharedPropertyProvider == nil)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    
    // return
    return [sharedPropertyProvider.class sharedInstance];
}
```

It's protocol based.  We put this protocol on every class we have with a shared instance where we need to do this.

```
@objc (KVASharedPropertyProvider)
public protocol KVASharedPropertyProvider: AnyObject
{
    @objc (sharedInstance)
    static var sharedInstance: AnyObject { get }
}
```

The above works fine in Objective-C (and when called from Swift).  When attempting to write the same equivalent code in Swift, however, there appears to be no way to do it.  If you take this specific line(s) of Objective-C code:

```
NSObject<KVASharedPropertyProvider> *sharedPropertyProvider = [aClass conformsToProtocol:@protocol(KVASharedPropertyProvider)]
    ? (NSObject<KVASharedPropertyProvider> *)aClass
    : nil;
```

And attempt to convert it to what should be this line of Swift:

```
let sharedPropertyProvider = aClass as? KVASharedPropertyProvider
```

... initially it appears to succeed.  The compiler just warns you that sharedPropertyProvider isn't be used.  But as soon as you attempt to use it like so:

```
let sharedInstance = sharedPropertyProvider?.sharedInstance
```

It gives you the compiler warning back on the previous line where you did the cast:

> Cast from 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type') to unrelated type
> 'KVASharedPropertyProvider' always fails

Any ideas?  Is Swift simply not capable of casting AnyClass to a protocol in the same way that it could be in Objective-C?

In case you're wondering why we need to do this, it's because we have multiple xcframeworks that need to operate independently, and one xcframework (a core module) needs to optionally get the shared instance of a higher level framework to provide special processing if present (i.e. if installed) but that processing must be initiated from the lower level.

**Edit:**

It was asked what this code looked like in Swift (which does not work).  It looks like this:

```
static func shared(forClass aClass: AnyClass) -> AnyObject?
{
    guard let sharedPropertyProvider = aClass as? KVASharedPropertyProvider else
    {
        return nil
    }
    
    return type(of: sharedPropertyProvider).sharedInstance
}
```

The above generates the warning:

> Cast from 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type') to unrelated type
> 'KVASharedPropertyProvider' always fails

It was suggested I may need to use KVASharedPropertyProvider.Protocol.  That looks like this:

```
static func shared(forClass aClass: AnyClass) -> AnyObject?
{
    guard let sharedPropertyProvider = aClass as? KVASharedPropertyProvider.Protocol else
    {
        return nil
    }
    
    return type(of: sharedPropertyProvider).sharedInstance
}
```

And that generates the warning:

> Cast from 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type') to unrelated type
> 'KVASharedPropertyProvider.Protocol' always fails

Comment: Post your full version of `sharedInstanceForClass` in Swift. This is almost certainly pretty straight-forward to solve, but please don't make us reverse engineer you whole function to get there. Post a minimal example that fails, but if the thing you want were fixed, would be your answer. (The short answer is it's almost certainly going to be `= aClass as? KVASharedPropertyProvider.Protocol`, because you want a protocol metatype, not an existential type, but I can't test that without seeing the rest of your work.)

Comment: @RobNapier I posted an Edit section above with the sample code you're looking for.  I also tried as? KVASharedPropertyProvider.Protocol, as I understood you be suggesting, and it did not work for me.

Comment: severehed has the answer. You want `.Type` rather than `Protocol`.

Comment: severehed's solution doesn't work for me because the use of the generic in this context resulted in a warning: "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred". I think that's because I'm starting with AnyClass.

Comment: I meant his first (non-generic) solution. `return (aClass as? SharedProvider.Type)?.shared`. (This whole thing is very ugly for Swift; I would rethink why you're porting it from ObjC. You may want to give an example of how you're actually using it, because it's got to be very messy. AnyClass and AnyObject are not things you want to work with in Swift any more than you absolutely have to. But I don't see why you wanted this code in ObjC, either.)

Comment: @RobNapier It looks like you got me to the answer.  Using KVASharedPropertyProvider.Type seems to be working.  If you want to post that answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @RobNapier I stand corrected.  I'll mark secerehed's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I assume you have something like this

```
protocol SharedProvider {
    static var shared: AnyObject { get }
}

class MySharedProvider: SharedProvider {
    static var shared: AnyObject = MySharedProvider()
}
```

If you want to use AnyObject/AnyClass

```
func sharedInstanceForClass(_ aClass: AnyClass) -> AnyObject? {
    return (aClass as? SharedProvider.Type)?.shared
}
```

Better approach

```
func sharedInstanceForClass<T: SharedProvider>(_ aClass: T.Type) -> AnyObject {
    return T.shared
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me because the use of the generic in this context resulted in a warning:  "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred".  I think that's because I'm starting with AnyClass.

Comment: While the generic solution didn't work for me, the version which used .Type did.  Thank you.